# How to create a dynamic link button in angular

Tags: angular, button, routes

I'm trying to create some responsive buttons that will navigate using the angular routing to certain pages. I've configured the routing as follows:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
  { path: 'user', component: UserComponent},
  { path: 'help', component: HelpComponent},
  { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent},
  { path: 'message', component: MessageComponent},
  { path: 'gallery', component: GalleryComponent},
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  { path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent},
  { path: 'bookings', component: BookingsComponent},
  
  { path: '', redirectTo:'home', pathMatch: 'full' } //redirect to 'home'
  // to be done. Wildcard for 404 page not found {path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent}
];
```

And the HTML code that doesn't work is:

```
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <div *ngFor="let item of menuItems">
  <ng-container >
      <a routerLink= {{item.address}} routerLinkActive="active-link"> </a>
    <div [fxShow]="!item.showOnDesktop" [fxShow.sm]="!item.showOnTablet" [fxShow.xs]="!item.showOnMobile">
      <button mat-menu-item>
        
        <mat-icon class="mr">
          {{item.icon}}
        </mat-icon>
        {{item.label}}
      </button>
      <mat-divider></mat-divider>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</div>
</mat-menu>
```

It seems that no matter how I try, the button isn't bind to the link. The buttons do nothing.
If I navigate manually to eg. "/home" it works.

I also have an interface called "MenuItems":

```
export interface MenuItem {
  label: string;
  icon: string;
  showOnMobile: boolean;
  showOnTablet: boolean;
  showOnDesktop: boolean;
  address: string;
}
```

Which has instances like this:

```
 menuItems: MenuItem[] = [
    {
      label: 'Home',
      icon: 'home',
      showOnMobile: false,
      showOnTablet: true,
      showOnDesktop: true,
      address: '/home'
    },
```

How can I get the buttons to be linked to the pages? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  <a routerLink="item.address" routerLinkActive="active-link"> </a>
```

If not try to change       `address: '/home'` to       `address: 'home'`

Hope useful

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not with the link, but with the {{item.label}}.

Lower, the link should have been put on the label. This way, when you clicked the button, it would work.